# Is card.io sdk free to be used for android and iphone development

Tags: card.io

I am android and iphone developer.I want to use card.io sdk in my own application.I have created a token for my app on card-io site.I want to ask if it is free to use this sdk or i have to pay some token amount to integrate sdk with my own app?

Answer (score 8):

Dave from card.io here.

You may indeed use the card.io SDK in your app at no expense. It is completely free.

Comment: Dave , I am unable to scan any of my cards. Why is that? Check my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283620/not-scanning-credit-debit-cards-card-io

Comment: Asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864303/cardio-cant-get-my-card-info/20204848?noredirect=1#comment37529814_20204848