# Card.IO SampleApp does not show card information

Tags: ios, card.io

I am using Card.IO to read credit card information. However, when I run SampleApp in the SDK folder. The code seems to read the card successfully. But the application is stuck in the camera screen, it did not move to previous screen and show card info. How can I solve this problem? I have added app token to this app.

Thanks

Comment: haisergeant is this the same problem described and answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19864303/cardio-cant-get-my-card-info/20204848 ?

Comment: I have tried many cards but none of them are recognized :(

Comment: Hmm. Well, card.io only scans 5 card types (MasterCard, Visa, Discover, American Express, JCB), and only with the traditional large embossed card numbers. It does sometimes have problems with cards that have complex background patterns, low contrast between background and numbers, etc. Without seeing your particular cards I can't offer any specific reasons as to why they are not working for you, but does this information provide any hints?